# Access a specific property in deeply nested json using c# and add it to an array

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I am trying to access all the values of OperationId in the below json and add it to an array, but it keep giving me a null exception as I drill down the data. Below is the json, any suggestion on how I can access operationIds directly are appreciated.

**A Note: All the controller Names & HttpVerbs are variable throughout the json, this is just a small part from a 10,000 line Json file, so hardcoding each value to get a string doesn't work.**

Json:

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "version": "v1",
        "title": "API Services"
    },
    "host": "TestApi.Com",
    "basePath": "/TestApi",
    "schemes": ["https"],
    "paths": {
        "/activity/actions": {
            "get": {
                "tags": ["activities"],
                "summary": "Returns a list of non-hidden Actions.",
                "description": "Test Description",
                ***"operationId": "GET/activity/actions",  //Need to add this to array***
                "consumes": [],
                "produces": ["application/json", "text/json", "application/xml", "text/xml"],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "OK",
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "$ref": "#/definitions/ActionResponse"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "put": {
                "tags": ["activities"],
                "summary": "Updates any/all existing ActivityActions by matching Id",
                "description": "Test Description",
                ***"operationId": "PUT/activity/actions", //Need to add this to array***
                "consumes": ["application/json", "text/json", "application/xml", "text/xml", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],
                "produces": ["application/json", "text/json", "application/xml", "text/xml"],
                "parameters": [{
                    "name": "List`1",
                    "in": "body",
                    "required": true,
                    "schema": {
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/ActivityActionPutRequest"
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    "name": "Authorization",
                    "in": "header",
                    "description": "AccessToken",
                    "required": false,
                    "type": "string"
                }],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "OK",
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "$ref": "#/definitions/ActivityActionUpdateResponse"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "/activity/agency-url/create": {
            "get": {
                "tags": ["activities"],
                "summary": "Test",
                ***"operationId": "GET/activity/agency-url/create",  //Need to add this to array***
                "consumes": [],
                "produces": ["application/json", "text/json", "application/xml", "text/xml"],
                "parameters": [{
                    "name": "EntityType",
                    "in": "query",
                    "description": "Test",
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "string"
                }, {
                    "name": "EntityId",
                    "in": "query",
                    "description": "The Guid or Sequence No of the entity.",
                    "required": true,
                    "type": "string"
                }, {
                    "name": "Authorization",
                    "in": "header",
                    "description": "AccessToken",
                    "required": false,
                    "type": "string"
                }],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "OK",
                        "schema": {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/ActivityUrlResponse"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So Output will look like:

```
[GET/activity/actions, PUT/activity/actions, GET/activity/agency-url/create]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First define the JSON structure - this is only minimal structure that was needed to read the field you wanted:

```
public class RootJson
{
    public Paths paths { get; set; }
}

public class Paths : Dictionary<string, ActivityActions> { }

public class ActivityActions
{
    public Get get { get; set; }
    public Put put { get; set; }
}

public class Get
{
    public string operationId { get; set; }
}

public class Put
{
    public string operationId { get; set; }
}
```

Then extract the data like this (I'm reading all gets then all puts, you may want a different ordering):

```
var json = "{ ... define your json }";
var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootJson>(json);

var result = new List<string>();
result.AddRange(test.paths.Select(p => p.Value.get?.operationId).Where(oid => oid != null));
result.AddRange(test.paths.Select(p => p.Value.put?.operationId).Where(oid => oid != null));
```

Now result holds the list you want.

Answer (score 1):

So I would to use [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)'s methods.

Something like this:

```
private static IEnumerable<JToken> GetToFindPropertiesAsJTokens(string json)
        {
            IEnumerable<JToken> jTokens = null;
            JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
            jTokens = jObject.Descendants()
                .Where(t => t.Type == JTokenType.Property && ((JProperty)t).Name == "operationId")
                .Select(p => ((JProperty)p).Value);
            return jTokens;
        }
```

Using:

```
 List<string> values = new List<string>();
 foreach (JToken jtoken in GetToFindPropertiesAsJTokensBasedOnTable(json))
 {
     values.Add(jtoken.ToString());
 }

 string[] valuesArray = values.ToArray();

 Array.ForEach(valuesArray, x=> Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Output:

```
GET/activity/actions
PUT/activity/actions
GET/activity/agency-url/create
```